# V-for with 3000+ recs loading REALLY slow (12+ seconds)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have an array of about 3000 objects (from a web service) that I am rendering using a `v-for`.

my array looks like:

```
this.oParts = [
 {
 descript: 'my descript',
 partno: '1234567890123',
 partsid: '1234567890'
 partscatid: '1234567890',
 partscat2id: '1234567890'
 serialized: true,
 category: 'test',
 subcat: 'test-2'
 uofm: ''
 },
.
.
.3000 times
]
```

To render, I using vuetifyjs:

```
<v-container>
   <v-row v-for="(x, index) in oParts" :key="index">
     <v-col>
      <!-- v-model.lazy="x.selected" -->
            <v-checkbox
                  value="false"
                  :label="x.descript + ' (' + x.partno + ')'"
                   :messages="x.partsid + (x.serialized ? ' (serialized)' : '')"
                    class="notes-chkBox"
                    color="primary"
                    @click.capture.stop="btnOKClicked(x)"
                    >
                    </v-checkbox>
              </v-col>
          </v-row>
</v-container>
```

This is taking over 12 seconds to load. I am using Vue.js version 2.6.10 and vuetify.js version 2.0.15

I've tried using v-once and the Object.freeze() mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/6ajcu5/vfor_poor_performance/) but that doesn't seem to help. I don't really need 2 way data-binding here. Are there any other ways to speed up the rendering of this list?

Comment: Couple of thoughts/comments. First, do you know that all (most) of the delay is rendering and not network delay in returning the response? Probably so, but worth checking to make sure you're not trying to optimize the wrong thing. Second, do you really need to display 3000 items? Seems like that might be overwhelming to users. Can you get away with paging? You might also look at virtual-repeaters/virtual-scrollers

Comment: @StephenThomas Yes, I've ruled out the network. No, I don't have to display 3000 items at once (pages aren't really an option though). Basically, there are 3000 parts to choose from and they can scroll to a part (if it's low enough in the alphabet or I have some filters they can type into until the list is small enough that they can scroll it and find the part they want. I'll look into virtual-scrollers. Thanks

Comment: I tried running this myself and saw similar rendering times, roughly 12s. Each row contributes 13 elements to the DOM, so with 3000 rows you're going to have nearly 40000 elements. While the majority of the 12s does seem to be Vue creating components, VNodes, etc. there is also a pretty big chunk of browser style calc and layout stuff. Even if you could use trickery to skip the overhead added by Vue you're going to struggle to keep user interactions quick with so many elements. Bottom line is you'll need to find some way to avoid rendering so much stuff at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using a virtual-scroller was the way to go. I found this one designed for Vue.js that took it from 12 seconds to near instant.

https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller

new html:

```
<v-container>
<RecycleScroller
   class="scroller"
   :items="oParts"
   :item-size="65"
   key-field="partsid"
   v-slot="{ item }"
   >
   <v-row>
      <v-col>
         <v-checkbox
            value="false"
            :label="item.descript + ' (' + item.partno + ')'"
            :messages="item.partsid + (item.serialized ? ' (serialized)' : '')"
            class="notes-chkBox"
            color="primary"
            @click.capture.stop="btnOKClicked(item)"
            >
         </v-checkbox>
      </v-col>
   </v-row>
</RecycleScroller>  
</v-container>
```